# Laravel request validation choice

Tags: laravel

I am wondering if it is indeed possible to do "you either need to provide a phone number OR email address."

Currently my request is

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email_address' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required|min:3',
    ];
}
```

Would I do this with an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `required_without` rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email_address' => 'required_without:phone|email',
        'phone' => 'required_without:email_adress',
        'body' => 'required|min:3',
    ];
}
```

By the way I'm pretty sure that some people have a 2 letters first name.

Comment: Thanks for that, and thanks for the reminder with the first name!